# ScrollView для fragment

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Здравствуйте, господа. На андроиде новичек вот и первый запар появился.

Сразу к делу Вообщем у меня есть фрагмент и закидываю ее лейоут главного активити
а там есть ScroolView так вот он мне теперь все мои листы в размер одного листа запихнул. Все испробовал[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Помогите

### Xml основного блока куда кидаю фрагмент

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.serik.astanawebmarket.fragments.ListFragm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

### xml фрагмента

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSalary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPosition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"/>
```

кидаю так

List> aList = new ArrayList>();

```
    for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("tvName",  name[i]);
        hm.put("tvPosition","Должность: " + position[i]);
        hm.put("tvSalary", "Оклад: "+Integer.toString(salary[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    SpecialAdapter  adapter = new SpecialAdapter (getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_item, new String[] { "tvName","tvPosition","tvSalary" },
            new int[]{ R.id.tvName,R.id.tvPosition,R.id.tvSalary});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSalary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPosition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

В разметку фрагменты скролл перенесите и из "основного блока" удалите